# All google font weight are not loading in safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fonts, google-fonts

All font face are not loading  in safari but loading properly in chrome

```
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Overpass:wght@200;300;400;600;700;800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Only those fonts are loading
/* latin-ext */

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Overpass';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/overpass/v5/qFdH35WCmI96Ajtm81GrU9vgwBcIs1s.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0100-024F, U+0259, U+1E00-1EFF, U+2020, U+20A0-20AB, U+20AD-20CF, U+2113, U+2C60-2C7F, U+A720-A7FF;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Overpass';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/overpass/v5/qFdH35WCmI96Ajtm81GlU9vgwBcI.woff2) format('woff2');
  unicode-range: U+0000-00FF, U+0131, U+0152-0153, U+02BB-02BC, U+02C6, U+02DA, U+02DC, U+2000-206F, U+2074, U+20AC, U+2122, U+2191, U+2193, U+2212, U+2215, U+FEFF, U+FFFD;
}
```

Comment: that link definitely returns more than that - are you sure safari is getting more?

Comment: in the safari, does font-weight: defaults to just bold?

Comment: when i am fetching https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,800&display=swap      all fonts weights are being fetched

Comment: No i am giving proper font weight

Comment: would you mind providing screenshots of safari rendering and chrom rendering